# Convert TEXT file to JSON in Dataweave

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave, mulesoft

How can I convert TEXT file into JSON in Dataweave.

Input:

```
"[
  {
    "quantity": "1.0",
    "uom": "every",
    "amount": "5.0",
    "allocation": [
      {
        "ID": "22245",
        "price": "156",
        "desc": "Product A1"
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    "quantity": "2.0",
    "uom": "all",
    "amount": "65888",
    "allocation": [
      {
        "ID": "65665",
        "price": "7789",
        "desc": "Product A2"
      }
    ],
  }
]"
```

Expected output in JSON:

```
ex:
[
  {
    "quantity": "1.0",
    "uom": "every",
    "amount": "5.0",
    "allocation": [
      {
        "ID": "22245",
        "price": "156",
        "desc": "Product A1"
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    "quantity": "2.0",
    "uom": "all",
    "amount": "65888",
    "allocation": [
      {
        "ID": "65665",
        "price": "7789",
        "desc": "Product A2"
      }
    ],
  }
]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNuVl.png)

Comment: The JSON output seems to be missing the curly brackets because of the ex key should be an object?

Answer (score 3):

Use the read() function to parse the input string as JSON.

```
{
  ex: read(payload,"application/JSON")
}
```

Comment: I am getting input in a TEXT file that need to convert in JSON

Comment: The conversion is working. If the input has quotes it is parsed as a single JSON string. The format of your input doesn't match the input presented in the question. Which one is the right input?